# Passing extended choice parameter value from one job to another remote job in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am working on a scripted Jenkins pipeline, and I am using the **triggerRemoteJob** plugin to trigger a remote job on another Jenkins instance.

The remote job has an extended choice parameter.

The syntax for passing parameters to the triggerRemoteJob plugin seems to differ from the build Job plugin.

What is the correct syntax to pass the value of an extended choice parameter while using the triggerRemoteJob plugin?

**********EDIT**********

Posted an answer below.
If there is a way to solve the issue in Jenkins pipeline, please post it as an answer.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the pipeline code you are using and what errors are you getting?

Comment: @aalbagarcia I tried passing simply as a parameter, like this- triggerRemoteJob(job: "job",parameters: "key=value") while using the triggerRemoteJob plugin. Didn't get an error, but the (extended choice) parameter on the remote job wasn't populated with the value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no special class for those parameters. I've always used the String one and it works as long as you introduced a valid option:

```
string(name: 'PARAM', value: "option"),
```

--- EDIT ----

I do it with this syntax:

```
    build(job: 'my_job', parameters: [
      string(name: 'PARAMETER', value: 'value'),
    ])
```

Comment: I tried passing simply as a parameter, like this- triggerRemoteJob(job: "job",parameters: "key=value") while using the triggerRemoteJob plugin. Didn't get an error, but the (extended choice) parameter on the remote job wasn't populated with the value. It works for normal string paramters.

Comment: I've edited my original answer with the syntax that I use and that may work for you as well. Could you try that?

Comment: I have already tried it, and the error it gave me was:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.pipeline.RemoteBuildPipelineStep.setParameters() expects class java.lang.String but received class java.util.ArrayList. Which is why I had to do it this way: **triggerRemoteJob(job: "job",parameters: "key=value")**

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this issue thread in github:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/coordinator-plugin/issues/46

It seems that because the Extended choice parameter does not support an interface in jenkins, calling the triggerRemoteJob with an ext. choice parameter is not supported.